# Why do tops move opposite to each other when colliding, not tangentially?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, collision

When two well-balanced tops collide, they tend to bounce directly away from each, in other words along the line connecting their centers.

Intuitively I would expect the tops to move tangentially, not orthogonally.

What is causing them to move away from each other in this way?

Comment: Explain your intuition. I don't think it's that surprising, since you are basing your intuition probably off plastic toy tops, which you neither are capable of spinning ridiculously fast, nor do they deform much from the low speed collisions you performed. If I rotated a globe and flung a pebble at it, it would reflect perpendicular to the surface. Now throw a comparable size of silly putty at it and you'll no longer find completely perpendicular reflection (increasing deviation with increasing speed, thus your comment about believing directions of rotating not mattering, I believe incorrect).

Comment: The kicker is, more deformation, more contact with the globe, more radians the object is transferred through via the globe. Your intuition is (probably) built off reality rigid bodies.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is due to a combination of *Conservation* of total linear **AND** angular momentum *before* and *after* collision. Especially if they have the same mass, this will be more pronounced.

As accidentalfouriertransform pointed out, the spinning nature of tops must be considered too. Since they slow down (due to contact frictions), by *conservation* of total angular momentum, they must separate in a direction that will more efficiently increase their separation in order to conserve the **product** of *moment of inertia* and *angular velocity* of the system as a *whole.* This will result in a final state in which two tops will separate back-to-back in arbitrary directions in the lab frame. (The *direction* of separation is due to conservation of *linear* momentum while the *magnitude* of separation is due to conservation of *angular* momentum).

Comment: It really isn't. If the total linear momentum is zero, you can still have any arbitrary change in direction, so this doesn't explain why the collision has to be collinear.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy, I don't believe  that you can get arbitrary deflection, even in a zero linear momentum game. A two body collision is 1d, how can you suddenly introduce a second dimension? All forces in an ideal symmetric object collision will be along the axis of collision, thus the object remains on that axis. So, to me, it actually does explain the behaviour, though the explanation leaves a lot to be desired, as the question is trying to confound the problem. My comment to the question, I believe gets at why there might be confusion, and I believe this answer to be correct in a general sense

Comment: @NoviceC but it can't be a one-dimensional problem due to the angular momentum of the tops. The problem is two dimensional to begin with.

Comment: I think this deserves a far more rigorous approach than that provided by either answer so far.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy, sure. But are you really going to claim that the tops will move along the axis of angular momentum? There will be no forces along this axis. No force, no acceleration—no deviation. My point is, in the ideal case where there is no deformation to the objects, the contact between the two objects during the collision is infinitesimally short. Thus the interaction between the two tops has nothing to do with the spin. Think of a wall moving 100 m/s to the left, and you time to throw a ball at it as it passes you by. Does the ball bounce back to you, or get pulled with the wall?

Comment: Regardless, I was aiming to dispel that you get arbitrary change in direction from zero net momentum in two body collisions (as I stated). Ignore the fact there is a rotational symmetry, and only consider the translational one.  Then it really is 1d. If you want to make an argument about the rotational axis, then I'd need to be convinced that the spin matters in the first place—and that would have to do with, in my opinion, inelastic collisions.

Comment: @NoviceC The fact that you have to bring up the issues of elastic vs inelastic, infinitesimal duration, shows to me that the argument isn't based on general conservation grounds and has to do with dynamics instead! At a moment in time there's no translational symmetry, and only a discrete rotational symmetry by 180 degrees, so I don't see what symmetry has to do with it either.

Answer (score 2):

The important laws here are momentum conservation and angular momentum conservation.

There are two possible contributions to momentum. The momentum of the center of mass of the tops, and the instanateous momentum from the contact point of the scatter.

If the angular velocity of the top is large enough so that at its radius the speed is much larger than the center of mass momenta, the interaction will be grazing and momenta transferred according to the instantaneous speed vector at the surface of the touching tops. They will either separate tangentially if the spins are in the opposite direction  reducing their angular momentum, stop, if they are exact, or move in the almost same direction if the spins are in the same direction, getting linear momentum, and fall due to friction etc. (Two spinning satellites in the latter case would balance angular momentum with the separation between each other).

If the momentum is much larger than the effective impulse when the two spins touch due to the rotation, the direction of scatter will be in the direction of conserved momentum. If of a similar order of magnitude something in between the first and the second option, depending on the spins directions. Angular momentum will be conserved by the relative angular momentum between the tops.

Hope this is not too confusing .